# can I change user password in linux from java program?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to change user password in linux from java program by sending password in outputstream but it is not done.

My java program is like

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo passwd sampleuser");

OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();

InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();

PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(outputStream);

printWriter.write("123456");

printWriter.write("\n");

printWriter.flush();
```

My program fails here and it ask for password but I does not want this case.

Is there any possibility for providing password from java program ? can you suggest me,how I will do it successfully or is there any shell api's available for it.

Same thing is done successful when I try using shell script and calling it from my java program as

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash first.sh");
```

My shell script is

```
i="123456"

echo -e $i"\n"$i|sudo -S passwd sampleuser
```

It changes user password successfully.

Answer (score 5):

It will ask for password. Look at your shell script. You execute a command that asks for super user privileges(`sudo`). Your program will prompt for a password unless you run it as a super user.

To break down your shell script:

```
i="123456"

echo -e $i"\n"$i|sudo -S passwd sampleuser
```

`sudo -S` means :

*The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.*

And that is what your script is doing, it is setting password(`passwd`) for your `sampleuser` as `i`. And since you are using `-S` it is reading from the standard input,to which you have already given your variable `i`. And you are doing all this as a super user! keep that in mind.

Now look back at your java program and try for the changes accordingly. Do you have super user privileges when you run your program? No,you don't.

Comment: "Do you have super user privileges when you run your program? I guess not." --> I really hope not.

Comment: Exactly! I better edit that line to make better sense out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your approach fails. I suppose passwd uses a different stream.

But use [ExpectJ](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/) for this. It is made just for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for an answer, I just find a way with this lines :

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sudo", "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo \"user:newpassword\" | sudo chpasswd"} );
    p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your intention. This might be help the questionoer and further visitors either. You can doing that by click on the edit link underneath your post.